# Source of L’Hôpital’s 1696 Calculus textbook

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, reference-request, calculus

A calculus textbook I’m using references a calculus book of **L’Hôpital** in which he illustrates his rule, which is taught in many calculus classes.

Does anyone have a source as a scanned PDF? I’d love to show my students. Thank you!

Comment: See [Mathematical Treasure: l’Hospital’s Analyse des Infiniment Petits](https://www.maa.org/book/export/html/871243) in the [*Mathematical Treasures*](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/index-to-mathematical-treasures) section of the MAA's [*Convergence* web pages](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence).

Comment: Also available in [Google's book](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Analyse_des_infiniment_petits_pour_l_int/KKk-6ElWxq4C)

Comment: Multiple formats of the [French original](https://archive.org/details/analysedesinfini00lhos) including pdf are freely accessible on Internet archive, as is [Stone's English translation (1730)](https://archive.org/details/methodfluxionsb00stongoog).  Bradley et al. published a [modern annotated translation (2015)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319171142) with source material by Johann Bernoulli.

Comment: The word "source" can have various meanings:-) Much of this book is actually due to J. Bernoulli. Marquis de l'Hopital hired Bernoulli to teach him Calculus, and the result was this book.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a scanned copy of the 2nd edition (1716)
of the 1696 book "Analyse des infiniment petits, pour l'intelligence des lignes courbes", by "Mr le Marquis De L'Hospital".

at  https://archive.org/download/infinimentpetits1716lhos00uoft

HTH
Terry

Comment: In particular pages 145–147 in the book. However, the material is not necessarily presented in a way that makes it easy to recognize for a modern reader.